# blackberry push sdk service

Tags: blackberry

I have installed the Blackberry push SDK and I put the Tomcat in server with real IP. I used the simple sample-push-initiator and I register it in the device and it registers successfully.

The problem: when I try to send push notifications from the Tomcat server with the sample-push-initiator I get an error

```
ERROR: Unauthorized to communicate with the PPG at URL:    
  https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest with 
username: xxxxxxxx and and password: xxxxxxxxx
```

What causes this error and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass your username and password (from blackberry registration) with HTTP Auth Basic Method.

i.e : `https://username:password@pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest`